# Cannot connect to database with a config file

Tags: php, mysql

i use a file (`ss-config.php`) which contains informations about servor and database connection, here is the code of `ss-config.php` file:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'ssiphone');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
?>
```

but when i try to connect i got this error :

```
Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\ssiphone\classes\ConnectionManipulationBaseDeDonnees.php on line 21
```

this my code which suppose to cause problem :

```
class ConnectionManipulationBaseDeDonnees
{
   private $bdd;//attribut $bdd qui contiendra la connexion à la base 


   public function connection(){//fonction connection qui se charge de la connexion à la base de données
   include("../ssiphoneadmin/ss-config.php");
         $host=DB_HOST;
         $dbname=DB_NAME;
         $dbuser=DB_USER;
         $dbpsw=DB_PASSWORD;

         try{
            $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE]=PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;

            $this->bdd=new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname.','.$dbuser.','.$dbpsw.','$pdo_options);
            }
         catch(Exception $e)//en cas d`erreur, le catch est fait pour la rattrapper 
            {
            die('Erreur: '.$e->getMessage());
            }
   }//fin fonction connection
}//fin class
```

line 21 is the line which contain the `$this` statement.
THX in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the PDO constructor should look like this:

```
$this->bdd=new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpsw, $pdo_options);
```

as stated in the documentation:

```
PDO::__construct() ( string $dsn [, string $username [, string $password [, array $driver_options ]]] )
```

Comment: THX a lot, i have added a "." but i got this error : Erreur: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'SYSTEM'@'localhost' (using password: NO)  so i tried your suggestion and it worked, THX a lot again and thx for all..DAMP, KrTEK, marc B and all others :)

Answer (score 0):

```
     $this->bdd=new(PDO('mysql:host='.$host.'dbname='.$dbname.','.$dbuser.','.$dbpsw.','$pdo_options);
                                                                                      ^^^
```

You're missing a `.` at the spot i've indicated.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `.` between the last textual part and the last option (`$pdo_options`).

```
$this->bdd=new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname.','.$dbuser.','.$dbpsw.','.$pdo_options);
                                                                                    ^
                                                                                    |
                                                                                    |
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `.` on the line

```
$this->bdd=new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname.','.$dbuser.','.$dbpsw.','$pdo_options);
```

it should be

```
$this->bdd=new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname.','.$dbuser.','.$dbpsw.','.$pdo_options);
```